# Django returns invalid ajax response

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a ajax call in my django template file as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#wdsubmit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/audit/addwd/",
            data: $('form.wddetails').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
               alert('Added Successfully');
                $("#newwd").modal('hide'); //hide popup
            },
            error: function(msg){
                alert(msg.success);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Form:

```
class WDForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WDModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

and view in django is :

```
def addwd(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            updated_request = request.POST.copy()
            updated_request.update({'updated_by': request.user.username})
            form = WDForm(updated_request)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                response = simplejson.dumps({'success': True})
                return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json", mimetype='application/json')
            else:
                response = simplejson.dumps({'error': True})
                return HttpResponse(response , content_type="application/json")
```

Whenever I make a Ajax call it always returns error even though I have sent Success(Means the form is valid and data is successfully pushed to database).

I also tried to send response={'success':True} doesn't work.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Environment Details:
Python verion: 3.4
Django :1.7
Windows OS 8

I doubt on this line "  `response = simplejson.dumps({'success': success})`
"

Comment: You need to show your `form`, chances are the form fails on both attempts you made. Also, please fix your indentation after `if` block.

Comment: @Anzel Form is not failing, As I mentioned in the question that the data is successfully saved into database(It means that the form.is_valid is true)

Comment: then what about the `success` value came from? or you just missed the quote around the string? You need to show what's actually in your code. Also as you're doing ajax call, it makes more sense to check that as well. **Assume** some of your code is working is evil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) objects.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse({'foo':'bar'})
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I was struggling a lot to solve this issue and spend whole day to figure out the problem. Still I don't know what's wrong with simplejson.dumps() or json.dumps() function